# In PDFMergerUtility, is there any option to ignore errors?

Tags: java, pdf, merge, pdfbox

I have to merge a lot of pdf files, I get base64 coded from a SOAP Action, but the CSV files, from i, read the data for the Protokoll are sometimes not correct. It means, when the n^th data is not correct, it will nothing mergen. I need an option there, to ignore errors if it merges the files.

```
for(int i = 0; i<bm.size(); i++) {
    String wert = leser.getBundlingWert(fileName, qeuecnt, bundling);
    new Paket(fileName);
    isNewPaket = true;
    ut.addSource(Paket.outPutPdf);

    if(leser.getPrintMode(fileName, i).equals("SIMPLEX")) {
        for(int j = 0; j < bm.get(wert); j++) {
            int pf = leser.getPageFrom(fileName, j);
            int pt = leser.getPageTo(fileName, j);
            seitecnt += (pt - pf) +1;
            if(isNewPaket) {
                seitecnt = 0;
                isNewPaket = false;
            }
            else if(seitecnt>blattGrenze) {
                new Paket(fileName);
                ut.addSource(Paket.outPutPdf);
                seitecnt = 0;
                isNewPaket = false;
            }
        }
    } else if(leser.getPrintMode(fileName, i).equals("DUPLEX")) {
        for(int j = 0; j < bm.get(wert); j++) {
            int pf = leser.getPageFrom(fileName, j);
            int pt = leser.getPageTo(fileName, j);
            seitecnt += ((pt - pf) +1)/2;
            if(isNewPaket) {
                seitecnt = 0;
                isNewPaket = false;
            }
            else if(seitecnt>blattGrenze) {
                new Paket(fileName);
                ut.addSource(Paket.outPutPdf);
                seitecnt = 0;
                isNewPaket = false;
            }
        }
    }

    qeuecnt += bm.get(wert);
}               

try {
    ut.setDestinationFileName(path);
    ut.mergeDocuments(null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If i let this code run and one of the files got data not correctly, it merges nothing, but i need an option, where it ignores the incorrect one.

Comment: You should make your code more self-contained. E.g. it is completely unclear what this `ut` is which actually merges. And tell which pdf library you use.

Comment: As i wrote in the title, its pdfmergerutility!

Comment: You did not write that `ut` is a pdfmergerutility; thus, `ut` might still be a wrapper of yours around that pdfmergerutility. Furthermore, what is pdfmergerutility? I know `PDFMergerUtility` which is part of PDFBox. But if you meant that, you would have tagged your question [tag:pdfbox] and had used the correct capitalization of the class name.

Comment: And even if we ignore this for the time being, it is unclear what kind of incorrect values your want to ignore. Thus, please clarify. And there are a lot of lines in your code which apparently are called for their side effects, e.g. all those `new Paket(fileName)` lines which completely ignore the constructed `Paket` instance...

Comment: So i think you are Just ignoring the answer. Altough i corrected the capitalization and the tags, if you can it better understand it like this...

Comment: And to clear, it is a good working code, i Just wanted to know, if there is an option to ignore the errorcases in merging. So if it founds an Errror in a pdf, it wont gives an exception. In this case, it should do the merging without the file with error

Comment: What happens in case of an error? You say *"it merges nothing"*. But what happens instead? Ist an exception thrown? Which one? With which stack trace? Or is the code here not executed at all? Or what?

Comment: Ok, so it throws IOException on the line "ut.mergeDocuments()" and the execution stops. I need a setting, where it not happens, but i get a merged PDF without the incorrect Page

Comment: As asked above, "With which stack trace?" I assume, though, that an `IOException` getting back to you indicates a situation the developers of the `PDFMergerUtility` have chosen not to handle explicitly themselves. Apparently they assume that the input they get is valid. Most likely, therefore, you will have to check the data you feed into that class, e.g. test whether the files in question exist and access to them is permitted, whether they are valid PDFs and have the start and end pages you respectively set for them, etc.

Comment: IMHO the best would be to load the PDF files separately, and to ignore those that throw an exception. Then use `appendDocument` instead of `mergeDocuments`.

Comment: Re the discussion in the first few comments, SO isn't a site where you dump some code and it will be fixed magically. The problem with the question is that most of the code is not relevant. Also no  idea what role the "base64" and "csv" and "SOAP" play in this. The core question is relevant. My previous comment should fix most problems; but if merging aborts in the middle of one append then the destination might be in some intermediate state so I think it would be better to save the merge result so one can keep all that is good.

Comment: Oh, yes i can understand it and Thanks, the problem is the data comes from a CSV file most of the time more than 5000 rows, so check all of them is impossible. But if its not possible to ignore these cases, than it also no problem. Logs are going to help. Thank you for help

Comment: Well, you can of course catch such exceptions and only in case of an exception go through the CSV a second time and do check the data. Then you can ignore the invalid datasets.